# package org.openqa.selenium does not exist

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am getting the following error in Jenkins.

The tests run in Eclipse when I run as Maven tests.

I have also set the Maven dependency option to compile.

My POM has all the dependencies. I can see all the dependencies in Eclipse.

Not sure why I am still getting `package does not exist`.

I have tried all other solutions given in StackOverflow. Can someone please help?

Thanks

```html
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[3,24] error: package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[3] error: static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[18,28] error: package org.apache.commons.io does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[19,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[20,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[21,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[22,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[23,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[24,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[25,39] error: package org.openqa.selenium.interactions does not exist
    [ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\base\TestBase.java:[23,16] error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class WebDriver
  location: class TestBase
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\LicensePage.java:[3,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\LicensePage.java:[4,34] error: package org.openqa.selenium.support does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\LicensePage.java:[5,34] error: package org.openqa.selenium.support does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\LicensePage.java:[12,1] error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class WebElement
  location: class LicensePage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\HomePage.java:[4,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\HomePage.java:[5,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\HomePage.java:[6,39] error: package org.openqa.selenium.interactions does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\HomePage.java:[7,34] error: package org.openqa.selenium.support does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\HomePage.java:[8,34] error: package org.openqa.selenium.support does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\HomePage.java:[9,37] error: package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\HomePage.java:[10,37] error: package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui does not exist
[INFO] 100 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.maven.reporters.MavenArtifactArchiver$2; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.maven.reporters.MavenFingerprinter$1; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.771 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-17T13:30:18+11:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project story-master: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[3,24] error: package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[3] error: static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[18,28] error: package org.apache.commons.io does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[19,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[20,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[21,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[22,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[23,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[24,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[25,39] error: package org.openqa.selenium.interactions does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[26,34] error: package org.openqa.selenium.support does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[27,34] error: package org.openqa.selenium.support does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[28,37] error: package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[29,37] error: package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[30,37] error: package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\base\TestBase.java:[11,28] error: package org.apache.commons.io does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\base\TestBase.java:[12,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\base\TestBase.java:[13,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\base\TestBase.java:[14,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\base\TestBase.java:[15,33] error: package org.openqa.selenium.chrome does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\base\TestBase.java:[16,34] error: package org.openqa.selenium.firefox does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[38,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebDriverWait
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[39,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Actions
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[40,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class JavascriptExecutor
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[46,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[49,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[52,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[55,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[58,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[61,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[64,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[67,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[70,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[73,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[76,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[79,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[82,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[85,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[88,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[91,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[94,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[97,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[100,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[103,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[106,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[109,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[112,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[115,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[118,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[121,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[124,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[128,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[131,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[134,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[137,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[140,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[143,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[146,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[149,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[152,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[155,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[158,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[161,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[164,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[167,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[170,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\pom.xml to com.yellowfin.installer/story-master/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/story-master-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[173,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[176,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[179,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[182,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[185,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[188,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[191,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[194,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[197,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[200,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[203,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[206,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[209,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[212,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[215,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[219,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[223,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[226,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[229,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[232,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[235,6] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\StoryPage.java:[239,3] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class StoryPage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\base\TestBase.java:[23,16] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebDriver
[ERROR] location: class TestBase
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\LicensePage.java:[3,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\LicensePage.java:[4,34] error: package org.openqa.selenium.support does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\LicensePage.java:[5,34] error: package org.openqa.selenium.support does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\LicensePage.java:[12,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class WebElement
[ERROR] location: class LicensePage
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\HomePage.java:[4,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\HomePage.java:[5,26] error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\HomePage.java:[6,39] error: package org.openqa.selenium.interactions does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\HomePage.java:[7,34] error: package org.openqa.selenium.support does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\HomePage.java:[8,34] error: package org.openqa.selenium.support does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\HomePage.java:[9,37] error: package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\story-master\src\main\java\Yellowfin\bi\qa\pages\HomePage.java:[10,37] error: package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui does not exist
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

Comment: Does your Jenkins build uses `settings.xml` with correctly set `<repositories>` section? Also does your selenium dependency has scope `test`?

Comment: no we do not use settings.xml and yes I have used the scope as test

Comment: I could get it working by running jenkins.war file rather than installing it using Jenkins windows executable, however I am not sure if this is the right approach

Comment: That is strange usually code from `src/main/java` should not use dependencies with scope `test` because those dependencies are for test execution only and not for production use. If you still need them change scope to `compile`